# Is there a reason a ML model would converge quickly on a substantial amount of training data?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a simple machine learning model using keras. I'm hoping to set the model up to perform scalar regression. The model I built reached convergence on the training loss incredibly quickly, after approximately 9 epochs. The training data consists of around 84000 examples consisting of 6 features.

I am running the model for 100 epochs with a batch size of 250. I am using a validation set which is 20% of the training set.

Since I'm running this on my local machine(Single CPU, no GPU) I was expecting it to take a lot longer to run to convergence, is there a reason this could be happening?

Here's the model definition:

```
def regression_model():
    model = keras.Sequential()

    model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu,
          input_shape(train_data.shape[1],)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation=tf.nn.relu))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(0.001)

    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae'])
    return model
```

Also when inspecting training and validation loss, I'm finding that they are roughly equal, what does this mean. any help that could be provided on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "speed" I assume you mean the *number of steps* to convergence. In this case, convergence speed has nothing to do with the hardware used -- that just improves the *time* (leaving aside the small effects that accelerators may have on numerical accuracy). The code you posted looks like a very simple model with few operations, so it's not surprising that it runs quickly on a cpu.

> Also when inspecting training and validation loss, I'm finding that they are roughly equal, what does this mean.

This is good, it means that you are not overfitting. If the validation loss becomes larger than the training loss this would indicate overfitting.

Comment: I had suspected the simplicity of the model could have something to do with it, so thanks for clearing that up.